# Frontpage and other tabs do not save "questions per page"

Tags: support, bug, front-page

I find this behaviour strange

- I click on button "30 per page" on the buttom of the Frontpage. Everything fine
- When I go to another tab (hot, newest,...) there are still 30 questions per page. Ok
- Now I refresh the page and still 30 questions shown. So what...
- But when I change the tab again, there are only 15 pages shown.

Info: Firefox on Windows 10